# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape'

Tags: c#, office-interop

I want to convert my `editShpID` to an int so I can get it's ID and add it to a list. I've tried Convert.ToInt32 however it won't convert and I'm not sure how I can do it another way.

My code is as fallows.

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;
            editedShpID = null;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShape in slide.Shapes)
                {
                    if (editedShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        editedShp = editedShape;
                        var textFrame = editedShape.TextFrame;
                        if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                        {
                            var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
                            pps += editedShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                            foreach (char word in textRange)
                            {

                                l.Add(word);
                                Debug.WriteLine(word);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    editedShpID = Convert.ToInt32( editedShape.Id);
                    editedShapesListID.Add(editedShpID);

                }
```

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;` - why is this a `Shape` if you want it to be an `int`? And can you not just do `editedShapesListID.Add(Convert.ToInt32( editedShape.Id));` ?

Comment: ` editedShpID = Convert.ToInt32( editedShape.Id);` That's the line that's given me the issue and I want to be able to use the Shape properties that's why I have it declared as a shape

Comment: Well, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape` is a Int64 (long) ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.id(v=office.14).aspx ) so, you should use a long, not a int. If you try to convert, and it is greater the Int32.MaxValue, or less than Int32.MinValue, you'll get an `OverflowException` ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4haekc4(v=vs.110).aspx )

Comment: @Magnetron I've tried `editedShpID = Convert.ToInt64(editedShape.Id);` and I still get the same error

Comment: @CraigGallagher editedShape.Id is already an Int64, so you don't need to convert

Comment: Just saw something, editedShpID is a Shape, not a Int, so why are you trying to assign an Int to it?

Comment: I want to be able to use the `Shape` properties as I'm adding the ID to a list and them I'm doing something like this `editedShpID.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB`

Comment: If you want the `Shape`object, why are you dealing with it's Id? Just cretae a List of Shape and add the `editedShape`.

Comment: I need the shape ID as I'm comparing 2 lists of shapes in 2 seperate PowerPoints and I need to compare it by checking if the IDs are the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133964/discussion-between-magnetron-and-craig-gallagher).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign an int to a shape object, change

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShpID;
```

to:

```
int editedShpID;
```

or do the list adding like:

```
editedShapesListID.Add(editedShape.Id);
```

Comment: I want to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape`as I want to be able to access the shape properties and I want to use the variable `editShape` as it's part of my foreach

Comment: Then define a list of shapes not ints, and do this : editedShapesList.Add(editedShape);

Comment: I need to know the shapes ID as I'm comparing 2 lists of shapes in 2 seperate PowerPoints and I need to compare it by checking if the IDs are the same

Comment: But you already have the id inside the editedShape, you can get to it using a linq maybe?

Comment: @CraigGallagher if you store the whole shape in the list, then afterwards when you do your comparison, you just access the Id property of each shape in the list in order to compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Your editedShpID(declared in first line) is of `Shape` type and you trying to assign `int`. Name your variable with correct names of you will be confused once again.

Here is your code with renamed variables:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape editedShape;
long editedShapeID;
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape slideShape in slide.Shapes)
{
    if (slideShape.HasTextFrame == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
    {
        editedShape = slideShape;
        var textFrame = slideShape.TextFrame;
        if (textFrame.HasText == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
        {
             var textRange = textFrame.TextRange;
             pps += slideShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
             foreach (char word in textRange)
             {
                 l.Add(word);
                 Debug.WriteLine(word);
             }
         }
     }

     editedShapeID = editedShape.Id;
     editedShapesListID.Add(editedShpeID);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I can keep it as a shape? I need to access its properties to do something like `editedShpID.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB` as I'm checking what colour that Shape ID has?

Comment: This is the point. Change name of `editedShpID` to `editedShp` and that gets much clearer. When you want to store Id of shape create a variable of type `Int64` and name it `editedShpID`.

Comment: @CraigGallagher I edited answer. Changed some variable names a bit. Now it should be clear what is what and what I mean.

Comment: I now get an exception on `editedShapeID` saying `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

Comment: You did something wrong in your code. In my code `editedShapeID` is long type variable. It can't throw that exception